# In Grails application The type org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy cannot be resolved

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm trying to write LogoutController in Grails-application. I've found a working code:

```
package myPackage

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
@Secured('permitAll')
class LogoutController {
    def index() { 
        if (!request.post && SpringSecurityUtils.getSecurityConfig().logout.postOnly) {
            response.sendError HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
            return
            }

            // TODO put any pre-logout code here

            redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl
    }
}
```

But an syntax error appears on the "package myPackage" string: `The type org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`

I tried to configure build path, where I've marked all in "Order and Export" list(I work in Grails Tool Suite(based on eclipse)), but all unsuccessful. How to fix it?

Comment: what is your file structure?

Comment: where the `LogoutController ` is located?

Comment: @injecteer, what kind of file you're talking about?

Comment: @injecter, it is a package, it consists of these groovy files: LogoutController, RegistrationController,SignController, StartPageController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Some strangely, but application works correctly with that error.